# Office Script - Delete rows from Excel table not containing specific text

Tags: ms-office, office-scripts

I have been working with an Office script in Excel (in conjuction with Power Automate) to delete all rows from a table. I now need to modify this so it excludes rows which contain specific text in one of the columns.

Is anyone aware of a way to do this? For example, if a column C row contains "No", do not delete the row.

The script used to delete all rows in the table is below but unsure how to modify this to exclude certain rows

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let table = workbook.getTable("Table1");
  let rowCount = table.getRowCount();
  table.deleteRowsAt(0, rowCount);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following script:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let table = workbook.getTable("Table1");
    let columnToCheck: number = table.getColumn("ColumnName").getIndex();

    let row = 1;
    let rowCount = table.getRowCount();
    while (row <= rowCount) {
        let text = table.getRange().getCell(row, columnToCheck).getText();
        if (!text.includes('No')) {
          table.deleteRowsAt(row - 1, 1);
          rowCount--;
        } else {
          row++;
        }
    }
}
```

It loops through the table, checks each value in `"ColumnName"` (be sure to replace this with the name of the column you want to check), and deletes the row if the value does not contains `"No"`. Hopefully this helps!